# Query Builder retrieving users by using Chunk method

Tags: laravel, query-builder

I want to display a table of `users` in my application, the maximum rows the table shows is 25 row, so instead of retrieving the 1500 user at once, i used `chunk` method to chunk the results by 25 row, but it returns an empty response.

```
        DB::table('users')->orderBy('id')->chunk(25, function (Collection $users) {
            return response()->json([
                'users' => $users
            ]);
        });
```

Comment: you can't return multiple responses ... and you are operating on each chunk, returning something from that closure wouldn't do anything ... all `chunk` is doing is getting 25 records at a time for you and letting you do something with them before then querying to get the next "chunk"